# COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Is it possible to execute COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT in Hibernate?

Comment: I'd like to see if there's a way to do this - specifically, allowing you to save an object to a Hibernate session and commit it to the database asynchronously. Converting the Hibernate code to plain SQL would not be an acceptable answer, though obviously executing some plain SQL to do the commit is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't search extensively but I couldn't find any evidence that you can access this functionality at the JDBC driver level.

And this leaves you with the option to specify the `COMMIT_WRITE` parameter at the instance or session level, if this makes sense for you.

Just in case, let me quote this blog post (I'm pasting the content for reference because the original site is either unavailable or dead and I had to use Google Cache):

> #### [Using "Commit Write Batch Nowait" from within JDBC](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aZkF4KwYL-QYJ%3ablog.orindasoft.com/2008/06/using-commit-write-batch-nowait-from.html+%22COMMIT_WRITE%22+oracle+jdbc+11g&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk)
>
> Anyone who has used the new
>   asynchronous commit feature of Oracle
>   10.2 will be aware that it's very useful for transaction processing
>   systems that would traditionally be
>   bound by `log_file_sync` wait events.
>
> `COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT` is faster
>   because it doesn't wait for a message
>   assuring it that the transaction is
>   safely in the redo log - instead it
>   assumes it will make it. This nearly
>   eliminates `log_file_sync` events. It
>   also arguably undermines the whole
>   purpose of commit, but there are many
>   situations where the loss of a
>   particular transaction (say to delete
>   a completed session) is perfectly
>   survivable and far more preferable
>   than being unable to serve incoming
>   requests because all your connections
>   are busy with `log_file_sync` wait
>   events.
>
> The problem anyone using Oracle's JDBC
>   driver is that neither the 10.2 or
>   11.1 drivers have any extensions which allow you to access this functionality
>   easily - while Oracle have lots of
>   vendor specific extensions for all
>   sorts of things support for async
>   commit is missing.
>
> This means you can:
>
> **Turn on async commit at the instance level by messing with the
>   `COMMIT_WRITE` `init.ora` parameter.**
>   There's a really good chance this will
>   get you fired, as throughout the
>   entire system COMMIT will be
>   asynchronous. While we think this is
>   insane for production systems there
>   are times where setting it on a
>   development box makes sense, as if you
>   are 80% log file sync bound setting
>   `COMMIT_WRITE` to COMMIT WRITE BATCH
>   NOWAIT will allow you to see what
>   problems you face if you can somehow
>   fix your current ones.
>
> **Change `COMMIT_WRITE` at the session level.** This isn't as dangerous as
>   doing it system wide but it's hard to
>   see it being viable for a real world
>   system with transactions people care
>   about.
>
> **Prepare and use a PL/SQL block that goes "BEGIN COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT;
>   END".** This is safer than the first
>   two ideas but still involves a network
>   round trip.
>
> **Wrap your statement in an anonymous block with an asynchronous commit.**
>   This is the best approach we've seen.
>   Your code will look something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> BEGIN
>
> --
>
> insert into generic_table
>
> (a_col, another_col, yet_another_col)
>
> values
>
> (?,?,?);
>
> --
>
> COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT;
>
> --
>
> END;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to do this but couldn't get it working in a test. The reason for my hold up was that I was expecting the wrong results from my test. I was testing by manually acquiring a shared table lock to simulate adding an index - but in this case, the `insert` query acquires the lock, not the `commit`. So it doesn't actually solve the problem I was looking to solve. I got round my problem by moving these insertions into a background queue, so that they don't hold up the main web request.

Anyway I think you can still do asynchronous commits in Hibernate. Basically you can use the `Session.doWork()` method to get access to the native `Connection` object (or in older versions of Hibernate, the `Session.connection()` method). I also moved the commit SQL into a strategy interface, so that we can run our HSQLDB-based tests which wouldn't understand the Oracle specific SQL.

In fact, it may be fine to use `Session.createSQLQuery` and give that the SQL, avoiding having to directly use `Connection`. Try it and see how it works.

```
private NativeStrategy nativeStrategy = new OracleStrategy();

interface NativeStrategy {
    String commit();
}

public static final class OracleStrategy implements NativeStrategy {
    public String commit() {
        return "COMMIT WRITE BATCH NOWAIT";
    }
}

public void saveAsynchronously(MyItem item) {
    session.save(item);
    session.flush();

    // Try to issue an asynchronous commit where supported.
    session.doWork(new Work() {
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            Statement commit = connection.createStatement();
            try {
                commit.execute( nativeStrategy.commit() );
            } finally {
                commit.close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```